# How to increase timeout setting in Gremlin Java Remote client?

Tags: java, gremlin, amazon-neptune

We are getting below exception while performing a load test on our application which is using Gremlin Java.
how to solve this issue?

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.RemoteConnectionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for an available host - check the client configuration and connectivity to the server if this message persists
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.traversal.step.map.RemoteStep.promise(RemoteStep.java:98 )
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.traversal.step.map.RemoteStep.processNextStart(RemoteStep.java:65 )
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.ut
```

Comment: Did you read it? Is there a configuration issue? Is it happening every time? Did it work earlier? You've left out so many details...

Comment: It looks to me as if your client is not even able to connect to the endpoint. The client is timing out waiting for a conenction. Are you running your code inside the VPC (perhaps from an EC2 instance) ? If not are you using something like an ELB to handle that transition?  Maybe an SSH tunnel? Please can you provide a lot more information about your configuration. Then hopefully it will be possible to help you make progress.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, Just checking in to see if you had any other followups on this post.

Comment: Too many connections is causing this issue. We have approached AWS Support. I will update if i have answer.

Comment: @SandeepKumarJakkaraju have you received an answer from AWS support? I am facing the same issue intermittently as well.

Comment: @SandeepKumarJakkaraju Im facing the same issue did you find the solution can you update please.

Answer (score 0):

"Timed out while waiting for an available host" -  This is most certainly a connectivity issue between your client and DB. There are numerous answers around debugging connectivity to Neptune, please try them out. To begin with, can you try the following from your client machine?

```
telnet <db-endpoint> <db-port>
```

You would most likely see that its waiting to establish the connection, which confirms this hypothesis.

In general, establishing a connection to the server is fairly quick. The only timeout that you need to worry about is query timeout, and Neptune has a parameter group entry for that.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/parameters.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But we had already increased the timeout for a drop query to empty database. Hence we ruled out this possibility.

Comment: Did you try telnet as recommended above? Is the issue still there?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. Neptunes does not logs error stack trace into logs. TimeoutException for me was coming when the cpu > 60 percent use case. The cpu would go this high, because of many connections being made to db.

Gremlin is based on websockets and multiple requests can be multiplexed and used via same channel. Adding `maxInProcessPerConnection` and `maxSimultaneosUsagePerConnection` did help me to reduce the error rate to 0 percent. These paramters set the count of process which will be multiplexed within  one connection. In my case around 50 workers concurrently read/write.
I observed that for my use case setting the values to 32 led to minimum cpu usage.
Below is the Cluster properties I am settling with for now.

By default Cluster keeps a pool of max 8 websocket connections if not mentioned. I was getting `TimeoutException` when `maxPoolSize` was set to 100.

```
                .addContactPoint(uri)
                .port(port)
                .serializer(Serializers.GRAPHBINARY_V1D0)
                .maxInProcessPerConnection(32)
                .maxSimultaneousUsagePerConnection(32)
                .maxContentLength(10000000)
                .maxWaitForConnection(10)
                .create()
```